# Error - Python - Mac - Opening file with addition of strings

Tags: python, macos, file, class, python-2.7

I've been trying to read some things from a file and when I give the open() command the whole address it gives me no problems:

```
    address = 'Languages/Menu/en.txt'
    file = open(address, 'r')
```

Even adding a string and a variable works:

```
    address = 'Languages/Menu/'
    pi = 'en.txt'
    address += pi
    file = open(address, 'r')
```

But when I try to add one string and a variable from a class it doesn't work:

```
    address = 'Languages/Menu/'
    address += options.language
    print address
    file = open(address, 'r')
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Languages/Menu/en.txt\r'

But the address printed is correct:   Languages/Menu/en.txt

Someone knows why this is happening? In windows works perfectly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
address += options.language
address = address.strip()
```

Comment: actually, `address.strip()` will take care of every nonprinting and whitespace character in one go

Comment: Thank you. 

I used:

    address += options.language 
    address = address.strip('\r').strip('\n)

in a function that I had for reading files. That's the function that creates the options.language variable in the class, apart from others.

Now it works perfectly and it still keeps the whitespaces. :D